# Fetching rows one by one from server using pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

I have a query that returns many rows and each row is large due to the presence of `BLOB`s that I need to fetch.

I make the query as follows:

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(...)
with db.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("select value from my_blobs")
    for row in cur:
        ...
```

I was naively expecting that iterating over `cur`, rather than calling `fetchall()`, would avoid getting all the data at once and running out of memory in the process. However, what I see is that memory runs out during the call to `cur.execute()`, that is, before I even try to get the results through `fetchall()`, `fetchone()` or by iterating over `cur`.

My question is, how can I get my blobs one by one? Am I bound to iterate in the application and make a new query for each blob? Then what is the use of `fetchone` or iterating over `cur` if the whole data is queried during `execute()` anyway?

Comment: Are you receiving a memory error? Please post exact exception message. And how many records are in *my_blobs* and what is the typical size of such blobs? Are they high resolution images? Large documents? Try multiplying typical size by row size. If your CPU does not have large enough RAM, memory error will occur.

Comment: @Parfait The question is essentially about whether/why records are retrieved during the query rather than when iterating during the records, and how to mitigate that. The fact that I run out of memory in my case is bad and provide some motivating background, but it is actually somewhat irrelevant to the question, as are details on what my blobs contain, I suppose.

Comment: @user1735003 Any luck with this? I have the same issue — it is fetching all and only then iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default cursor class is buffering data. Fortunately there is unbuffered version: `pymysql.cursors.SSCursor`. Try to run `db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)` instead of `db.cursor()`.

From the [API reference for `SSCursor`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.SSCursor):

> Unbuffered Cursor, mainly useful for queries that return a lot of data, or for connections to remote servers over a slow network.
>
> Instead of copying every row of data into a buffer, this will fetch rows as needed. The upside of this is the client uses much less memory, and rows are returned much faster when traveling over a slow network or if the result set is very big.